# Heroku: www subdomain returns "no such app"

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name, heroku

I recently set up my octopress blog at `http://davidmjohnson.me`. This domain works fine, but when I try `http://www.davidmjohnson.me`, I get a heroku "no such app" error. Why is the `www` not working? Do I need to add a redirect from `http://www.davidmjohnson.me` to `http://davidmjohnson.me`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the subdomain:

`heroku domains:add www.davidmjohnson.me`

There is nothing magical about the `www` subdomain. If you want to use it, you need to configure it. It sounds like you have done this in your DNS settings but not in your Heroku setup.

Comment: from the shell?

Comment: Yep. You'll need the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com).

Comment: Thanks that worked. Now for the sake of google analytics does it matter if people ping "http://d.." or "http://www.d" I just don't want it to be split.